# CloudWatch alarm doesn't trigger action if it changes state while having alarm actions disabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using `enable_alarm_actions() / disable_alarm_actions()` on CloudWatch alarm to implement mechanism for downtiming CloudWatch alarms.

If the alarm changed it state, while it's "downtimed" (`ActionsEnabled` property is set to `false`) it doesn't trigger corresponding action, as expected. But when you `enable_alarm_actions()` back the action on the alarm still not triggering. And you're running into situation, when you're not notified when the alarm went to `ALARM` state while being downtimed after downtime expires.

So, the question, is this expected and is there a way to manually trigger an action on the alarm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are describing, is that Cloudwatch wont trigger action when it is in alarm state and when you enable its action.

This is by design. Alarms invoke actions **only when alarm change** state occurs. Being in alarm state is not enough.

The docs [write](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html):

> Alarms invoke actions for sustained state changes only. CloudWatch
>   alarms don't invoke actions simply because they are in a particular
>   state, the state must have changed and been maintained for a specified
>   number of periods.

So when your actions are enabled when Alarm is already in alarm state, nothing is going to happen. You have to wait for next alarm state changes.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but sort of expected. This leaves second part of the question open: is it possible to programmatically trigger an action on alarm (via sdk / command line)?

Comment: @ChernikovP I don't think so. For sns, you can just manually send a msg to a topic using `sns` api. For autoscoling you would also need to use `autoscaling` api. But I'm not aware of any `cloudwatch` specific api for triggering the actions at will.

Comment: There is a `set_alarm_state()` API, so you could try changing the state back to OK and it should bounce back to ALARM and trigger the action.

Comment: I ended up checking alarm history to see whether the state changed during downtime and if it was, I manually send a msg to `sns` topic and handle it separately on receiver side (PagerDuty). Thanks for your replies, folks.